# What forms of discretionary access control are there?

Tags: filesystems, acl, access-control

I know it's kind of an unguided question, but just so I have a broader sense of how things are I was interested in getting a reasonably complete list of discretionary access controls available on Unix platforms and their adoption. I'm mostly interested in Linux DAC systems but any *nix platform should be interesting and/or applicable to my skillset going forward.

I'm already aware of the following:

- **Traditional Unix Octal Permissions** the Owner/Group/World bits we all love. Plus the sticky bit and the setuid and setgid bits.
- **POSIX ACL's** Octal-style permissions and file/directory-based mask settings (as opposed to being dependent on a `umask` system setting) set using the `setfacl` command. Available on most proprietary unix systems, *BSD, and the Linux kernel since the early 21st century.
- **richacl** Linux-only patchset that hasn't been incorporated into the vanilla kernel yet.  Implements NFSv4 access controls on local files.

I won't include systems like SELinux since those are more MAC-oriented than something accessible to regular users.